# error al insertar datos | PHP | MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Buenas tardes comunidad tengo un error al intento de registrar los datos en mi DB , ya revise que tenga una correcta conexion y ademas si lee los datos de la base de datos el problema esta cuando intento insertar un registro.

Mi archivo conexion:

```
<?php
     //CONECT DB
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);

     $usuario = 'usuario';
     $psd = 'passuser';
     $server = 'localhost';
     $db =  'winesther';

     $conn= mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $psd, $db);

     //Comprobaciones con la DB
     if( $conn ) {
        echo mysqli_get_server_version($conn) ;
      }

     if( !$conn) {
       echo mysqli_connect_errno();
     }
```

?>

En mi archivo de conexion no tengo problema ya que me da la salida de version del servidor de la base de datos.

Mi formulario de registro:

```
<form name="registerProduct" method="POST" >

<label>Titulo Producto</label>
<br>
<input  type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo del producto"  />
<br>
<label for="">Descripcion del producto</label>
<br>
<textarea name="descripcion" id="" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
<br>
<label for="">Precio</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="precio" placeholder="Precio producto" id="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">


</form>
<?php 
    include_once("enviar.php" );
?>
```

En mi archivo enviar.php se encuentra en la misma ruta de directorio que mis demas archivos que corresponden con los datos de envio.
Mi archivo enviar.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include('connect.php');

if( isset($_POST['enviar'])  ) {

$dato= "paso el IF";
echo $dato;
if( strlen($_POST['titulo']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['descripcion']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['precio']) >= 1 ) {

    $titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
    $descripcion = trim($_POST['descripcion']);
    $precio = trim($_POST['precio']);

    $query =  "INSERT INTO producto(titulo, descripcion, precio) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$precio') " ;
    $resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($resultado) {
            echo "Registro escrito";
        }

    if(!$resultado){
            echo "No se registraron los datos";
        }

}

}else {
    echo "completa los datos";
}
  ?>
```

Comment: El precio es `string`?

Comment: No, es un entero

Comment: BetaM aun teniendo el action="enviar.php" no lo envia pero igual pienso que sin incluirlo funciona ya que action= es otro tipo de envio si no me equivo ;,v.

Comment: Jaja ;,v esas rutas...

Comment: Ya realice la Prueba en local, debes colocar el **action** y listo envia y recibe sin ningun Problema

Comment: Banda ya quedo resulta resulta que tenia el problema en la ruta y en el action="" que no puse :p  Como menciono el Master BetaM. y en consecuencia actuo corroborando Josue Vargas justo despues de haberlo realizado yo tambien :b gracias bandita

Comment: Gracias Masters.

Comment: Listo ya puedes eliminar los comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion 2x1 error en path y asignacion falta de metodo de envio action="":

formulario forminsert.php me falto agregar el action="enviar.php"

```
<!-- 
 No tenia el action="" a donde se iba enviar si no lo tenia, a Detroit?
 :p agregue el action="enviar.php" verificando que estuviese en el path
 correcto.
-->
<form name="registerProduct" method="POST" action="enviar.php">

<label>Titulo Producto</label>
<br>
<input  type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo del producto"  />
<br>
<label for="">Descripcion del producto</label>
<br>
<textarea name="descripcion" id="" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
<br>
<label for="">Precio</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="precio" placeholder="Precio producto" id="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">


</form>
<?php 
include_once("enviar.php" );

?>
```

Resulta ser que tambien tenia un problema en la ruta

Codigo Anterior mal escrito enviar.php

```
 <?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 /*
  Movi mi archivo a mi path principal /enviar.php
  y estaba editando este backend/enviar.php 
 */
 //FIX
 include_once('connect.php');

 if( isset($_POST['enviar'])  ) {

 if( strlen($_POST['titulo']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['descripcion']) >= 1 
    && strlen($_POST['precio']) >= 1 ) {

    $titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);
    $descripcion = trim($_POST['descripcion']);
    $precio = trim($_POST['precio']);

    $query =  "INSERT INTO productos(titulo,descripcion,precio) VALUES 
    ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$precio') " ;
    $resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($resultado) {
            echo "Registro escrito";
        }

    if(!$resultado){
            echo "No se registraron los datos";
        }

}



}else {
     echo "completa los datos";
}

?>
```